# ¿Cómo puedo crear una curva a partir de 2 puntos?

Tags: java

```
public class grafico3 extends JFrame
{
    public grafico3()
    {
        setTitle("Prueba colores");
        //super("Prueba");
        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);

    }
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    /*g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(100, 100, 400, 400);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.setFont(new Font ("Serif",Font.BOLD,50));
    g.drawString("Rectangulo", 500, 500);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);*/
    g.drawLine(50, 50, 50,50);
    int x[] = { 20, 20, 20, 20 };
    int y[] = { 50, 50, 50, 50};  
    Polygon p= new Polygon(x,y,4);
    g.drawPolygon(p);
}
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        grafico3 g= new grafico3();
g.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podría haber simplificado el código para evitar un nuevo Objeto de tipo `Polygon` y pasar los arreglos directamente como parámetros al método [drawPolygon()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon-int:A-int:A-int-) *(Aunque la forma de pasar un objeto también es válido)*

Otra cuestión es que le está pasando los mismos puntos , tanto para las coordenadas de `X`  como de `Y` lo cuál no tiene tanto sentido, si cambia por los siguientes puntos seguro notará el dibujo.

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
  super.paint(g);
  int[] x = {100,200,300,400};
  int[] y = {400,300,300,100}; 
  g.drawPolygon(x,y,4);   
}
```

Si desea obtener una curva , podría emplear el método [drawArc(x,y,width,height,starAngle,arcAngle )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawArc(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) donde los parámetros serían

1. `x`- la coordenada x de la esquina superior izquierda del arco a dibujar.
2. `y`- la coordenada y de la esquina superior izquierda del arco a dibujar.
3. `width` - la anchura del arco a extraer.
4. `height` - la altura del arco a extraer.
5. `startAngle` - el ángulo inicial.
6. `arcAngle` - la amplitud angular del arco, en relación con el ángulo inicial.

   ```
   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
     super.paint(g);
     g.drawArc(100, 200, 10, 10 , 0, 180);
   }
   ```

> Sí desea obtener los valores de forma matemática, puede revisar [está
>   pregunta de SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196749/draw-arc-with-2-points-and-center-of-the-circle)

Comment: el problema es que lo grafica en linea recta, yo quiero que sea una curva

Comment: @AlonsoDanielBenitesSoto se me había escapado la finalidad de la pregunta. Revisar la actualización de mi respuesta. espero ayude.Saludos

Comment: Gracias me sirvio mucho